# Verifying probabilities equality by imposing conditions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, education

I'd like to verify the following equality in Mathematica:

$$
P(Z_1+Z_2=2,Z_1=1,Z_2=1)=P(Z_1=1,Z_2=1)
$$

by knowing that $Z_1,Z_2 \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ are two independent and uniform random variables.

Comment: What should P(z1+z2==2,z1==1,z2==1) mean?

Comment: Hello @DanielHuber the commas mean intersections

Comment: But in this case P(z1+z2==2,z1==1,z2==1) is a tautology, z1==1&& z2==1 imply z1+z2==2

Comment: @DanielHuber yes, is it possible to simplify the left term in Mathematica? The simplified one should be the right term

Comment: You may e.g. write your equations by zeros of polynomials and use Groebner Basis like:  `GroebnerBasis[{z1 + z2 - 2, z1 - 1, z2 - 1}, {z1, z2}]` Or you introduce a third variable and eliminate it like: `Eliminate[{z == z1 + z2 - 2, z1 == 1, z2 == 1}, z]`

Comment: `TautologyQ[Equivalent @@ FullSimplify @ { z1+z2 ==2 && z1==1 && z2==1, z1==1 && z2==1}]`

Comment: Hello @kglr where did you specify that z1 and z2 are random variables and their distributions?

Comment: Gennaro, I was elaborating on Daniel's comment, showing that `event1` and `event2` (where `{event1, event2} = {z1 == 1 && z2 == 1 && z1 + z2 == 2,   z1 == 1 && z2 == 1}`) are the same events; so regardless of the sample space these events reside in they will have same measure.

Comment: @kglr thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below calculates the two probabilities and allows you to verify that they are the same by inspection.

```
Probability[
 {z1 == 1 && z2 == 1, z1 == 1 && z2 == 1 && z1 + z2 == 2},
 {
  Distributed[z1, DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 4}]],
  Distributed[z2, DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 4}]]
 }
]

(*Out: {1/16, 1/16} *)
```

Comment: Hello @MarcoB thank you very much for your helpful code.

Comment: How did you specify the independence of the random variables?

Comment: @Gennaro They should be independent by default here. I think you'd have to work harder to indicate if they are somehow correlated.

Comment: if possible can you post the documentation where I can find this implicit hypothesis please?

Comment: I found it here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @MarcoB is almost always the way to go.  But if the set of equations ( `{z1 == 1 && z2 == 1, z1 == 1 && z2 == 1 && z1 + z2 == 2}`) is complicated enough such that `Probability` doesn't work, you might try a brute force method.

This approach simply creates the sample space of equally likely outcomes and then selects the outcomes that satisfies each condition.

```
sampleSpace = Flatten[Table[{z1, z2, z1 + z1}, {z1, 1, 4}, {z2, 1, 4}], 1]
(* {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 4}, 
    {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 4}, {3, 1, 6}, {3, 2, 6}, {3, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 6},
    {4, 1, 8}, {4, 2, 8}, {4, 3, 8}, {4, 4, 8}} *)

subset1 = Select[sampleSpace, #[[1]] + #[[2]] == 2 && #[[1]] == 1 && #[[2]] == 1 &]
(* {{1, 1, 2}} *)

subset2 = Select[sampleSpace, #[[1]] == 1 && #[[2]] == 1 &]
(* {{1, 1, 2}} *)
```

So the probabilities are both 1/16:

```
Length[subset1]/Length[sampleSpace]
(* 1/16 *)
Length[subset2]/Length[sampleSpace]
(* 1/16 *)
```